# Передача данных из UITableView на ViewController

Tags: swift, tableview, uiviewcontroller

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: Есть tableView , по клику на него нужно передать информацию из ячейки во всплывающий ViewController для подробного отображения информации. Так же создал модель , и в ListViewController был создан массив , по этой модели (в будущем ожидается работа с сетью , в данный момент хочу настроить шаблон приложения локально). Вопрос заключается в том , чтобы передать информацию из ячейки tableView во всплывающий viewController. Буду рад помощи более опытных коллег , заранее спасибо за помощь!

ViewController с tableView:

```
import UIKit
    
    let image = UIImage(named: "testImage")
    var movies: [Movie] = [Movie(name: "FirstMovie", overview: "some1", year: "2001", image: image!),
                           Movie(name: "SecondMovie", overview: "some2", year: "2002", image: image!),
                           Movie(name: "ThirdMovie", overview: "some3", year: "2003", image: image!)]
    
    class ListViewController: UIViewController {
        
        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
        
        
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            
        }
        
    }
    extension ListViewController: UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return movies.count
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let movie = movies[indexPath.row]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListCell" , for: indexPath) as! ListCell
            cell.setMovie(movie: movie)
            return cell
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            174
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as! DetailsViewController
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Всплывающий ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    var detailmovies: Movie?
    
    @IBOutlet var detailsImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var detailsName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var detailsOverview: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var detailsYear: UILabel!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        }
       
    
    func setDetail(movie: Movie) {
        self.detailsName.text = movie.name
        self.detailsImage.image = image
        self.detailsYear.text = movie.year
        self.detailsOverview.text = movie.overview
    }
}
```

Модель:

```
import UIKit

    struct Movie {
        var name: String
        var overview: String
        var year: String
        var image: UIImage
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще для таких целей можно просто передавать в ваш целевой ViewController модель данных. У вас происходит выбор элемента массива приблизительно так:

```
let model = movies[indexPath.section]
```

в конечном контроллере вы создаете переменную которая называется например так:

```
var model:Movie?
```

и при переходе вы ее передаете:

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as! DetailsViewController
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
vc.model = movies[indexPath.section]
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

ну а дальше уже можно с ней делать все то же самое что и на первом контроллере